# Cannot intercept HTTP requests that are initiated outside the browser e.g using the Windows Run box

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, httprequest

While developing an extension that requires interception of HTTP requests, we ran into an issue when navigation was initiated by entering the address into the Run box. After debugging and logging, it was observed that the event listeners had not been hooked before the navigation actually started even though the related objects were setup. Only after the window is opened and navigation has actually started, new navigations could be intercepted.

To see this, attach an event listener to the onBeforeRequest event of the extension's webRequest object, close the browser and start a new navigation using a shortcut link or by entering an address into the Run box for example.

Here's the relevant code:

```
// hook up the listener
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(onBeforeRequestCallback, { types:['main_frame'],urls:['*://*/*']}, ['blocking']);

function onBeforeRequestCallback(requestDetails) {   
     console.log('onBeforeRequestCallback called for request url:'+requestDetails.url);
}
```

The partial manifest json:

```
     "permissions": [
        "*://*/*",
        "tabs",
        "webRequest",
        "webRequestBlocking",
        "storage"
      ],

  "background": {
    "scripts": [      
      "background.js"
    ],
    "persistent": true
  },
```

Comment: This is a known old problem in Chrome's implementation of extensions: https://crbug.com/523634 - the background page script is loaded after a web page on browser startup.

Comment: @wOxxOm Ok, this seems to wrap it up. Should it be the answer? I think yes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, it's a [bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=523634).